# vscode: How to linkify text with a URL in HTML mode?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, hyperlink

Is there a way to quickly create a hyperlink in a HTML file given a text selection and a URL in the clipboard?

In markdown mode in vscode pasting a URL while some text is selected (e.g. `W3 Consortium`) will result in a markdown link being created, i.e. `[W3 Consortium](https://www.w3.org)`. (Similar functionality is also available in slack's richtext editor)

Is similar functionality available for the HTML mode, ootb or via an extension?

E.g. given a text selection of `W3 Consortium` by pasting a URL like `https://www.w3.org/` I expect to get:

```html
<a href="https://www.w3.org">W3 Consortium</a>
```

Currently the selection is simply replaced with the URL.

Is this available in vscode and if so then how to enable it? Or is there an extension that could do it? This is a pretty common use case so I assume it might be implemented but not clear what to search for.

Comment: **Emmet: wrap with abbreviation** then `a`, you can add it to a keybinding with arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done natively in vscode, but you can make a snippet/keybinding to it easily.  Make this keybinding, in your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+m",                          // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorHasSelection  && editorLangId == html",
  "args": {
      "snippet": "<a href=\"${CLIPBOARD}\">${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}<\/a>"
  }
}
```

You see it uses variables for your selected text and the clipboard content.  Demo:

[image: html link snippet]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!  The json config file can be opened form the Command palette (⇧⌘P) -> _Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)_

Comment:  a tiny tweak: to place the cursor at the end of the link text (rather than after the closing `</a>` tag) the snippet body can be modified to: `"<a href=\"${CLIPBOARD}\">${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}${1:}<\/a>"`

Comment: Just put a `$0` where you want the cursor to end up.

Comment: I updated your answer to restrict the `when` clause to HTML context only as per https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts.